# Define a Button using a String

Tags: android, arrays, image, button

Is there a way, rather than individually, to use an Array to define 10 buttons and their associated images, which I have in the res folder?

I have 10 buttons already created in my xml.

I have 10 custom button images in my resource folder.

Images are named my_button_0, my_button_1, ... and so on.

For example:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
    String z = "my_button_" + Integer.toString(a);
    Button z = findViewById(R.id.z);
    z.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.z);
}
```

Found several related questions, but not like this. Thanks.

Comment: In Java and Kotlin, you won't be able to have two variables with the same name (in your case: "z") in one scope. If this is essential to your question, the answer has to be "there is no way"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose buttons id are named button1,button2...., you could do like this:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
     int btnId = getResources().getIdentifier("button" + i, "id", this.getPackageName());
     Button btn = findViewById(btnId);
     int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier("my_button_"+i, "drawable", getPackageName());
     btn.setBackgroundResource(drawableId);
 }
```

Comment: Fantastic 'navylover'! That does indeed work. So now I can create an array of buttons, and adjust their images programmatically without having to do them individually. Thanks. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way as you mentioned. You can do something like this:

```
private int getButtonId(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return R.id.my_button_1;
        case 1:
            return R.id.my_button_2;
        case 2:
            return R.id.my_button_3;
        case 3:
            return R.id.my_button_4;
        case 4:
            return R.id.my_button_5;
        case 5:
            return R.id.my_button_6;
        case 6:
            return R.id.my_button_7;
        case 7:
            return R.id.my_button_8;
        case 8:
            return R.id.my_button_9;
        case 9:
            return R.id.my_button_10;
    }
}
```

// in your method

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
   Button z = findViewById(getButtonId(a));
   z.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.z); 
}
```